# How to install kenel headers for the kernel "linux-headers-4.14.0-xilinx" in debian 11?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-modules

I was trying to install `rtl8821au` downloaded from the link

```
https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au
```

driver module in the `Debian 11` rootfs.

I'm using kernel - `4.14.0-xilinx`

while following the steps i used the command

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then I got the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.14.0-xilinx
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.14.0-xilinx'
```

How to solve this issue? Any help will be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The package name is just: linux-headers.

For a particular version you can follow the package name with: =
and then the version numbers.